# How to remove addthis from my default template

Tags: plugins

One of biggest mistakes which I committed is that once I installed AddThis plugin and now it appears at the bottom of each page. I removed all the traces of plugin, changed the theme but all in vain. It appears at the bottom above footer in all the pages where I use default template. Please help.

[image]

Comment: How did you remove the plugin? List what you've done. Do you have a public link you can post?

Comment: Are you saying that you changed theme and it is still there? And you did remove the plugin properly? Open your .htaccess file and see if there is anything funky in there.

Comment: I have never heard about AddThis being badly behaved. Where did you get the plugin?

Comment: try grepping your entire wordpress folder for 'addthis'. From your root: `grep -irn "addthis" *`. It's bound to be in there somewhere.

Comment: @JPLew should I grep into wp-includes or wp-content

Comment: wp-content, because you want to search through your themes and plugins. wp-includes is part of Wordpress core so I doubt it would contain any references to AddThis.

Comment: @JPLew It worked, it turned out that SEO Ultimate was the real culprit. Thanks a ton. Please add this as an answer so that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try grepping your entire wordpress folder for 'addthis'. From your root: `grep -irn "addthis" *`. It's bound to be in there somewhere.

Check in `wp-content`, because you want to search through your themes and plugins. `wp-includes` is part of Wordpress core so I doubt it would contain any references to AddThis.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason this could happen is if you're using W3 Total Cache or WP Super Cache - in which case, clear your cache after removing the offending plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! At last! I had the same problem. It turns out there's a tick box on the Facebook Like widget settings with the comment 'Enable Other Social Buttons'. Toggle to 'no' and the floating nuisance disappears! You can check out [this page](https://justperryblog.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/deleting-the-addthis-floating-link-bar-a-solution/) for more.